# SSRS - SQL Server Reporting Services Possibility?

Tags: sql, reporting, sql-server

Currently, we have SQL Server 2012 R2. Looking to produce some reports and have them automatically run and have converted to PDF with the possibility of automating an email to send to subscribers of specific reports. Going back and forth in my mind about SSRS and Crystal Reports. Think I will go with SSRS.

If this isn't the correct area to post, please let me know.

Few Questions:

1) Is it possible to build a report once and then have it automatically run on a schedule?

2) Will it automatically save it as a pdf?

3) What version of SSRS would I need and is there a cost associated with what I am looking to do?

4) Am I assuming correctly that I can install SSRS on my desktop to then connect to the server to create the reports?

Thank you

Comment: Our IT dept is mid-process for leaving crystal and moving to SSRS.  No idea on internals, we access via web browser to pull reports as needed.

Comment: This forum is for software recommendations so you would be able to ask if there are alternatives to Crystal Reports and whether SSRS would meet your requirements. I am posting my response in comments as this would not a proper answer: 1. Yes. You can build once and add scheduling to the report. 2. Scheduled reports can be exported to - XML file with report data, - CSV, PDF, MHTML, Excel, TIFF  and Word 3. The latest version of SSRS will work and there is no cost for use as it is included with SQL Server. 4 Install Microsoft Report Builder tool, create your reports and then publish to SSRS

Answer (score 0):

To answer some of you question. Most of the email and pdf rendition would go through an SSRS Subscription that is on the server. A subscription can be set to email a specific group of users and also render your report as a PDF.

More info here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sO0Y_IxdE8w